# Blocked mixed content error in console when I try to edit a product in my magento

Tags: magento-1.9, category

When I try to click next product page in my magento admin panel, The loading never stop and when I go to console, it says like this.:

[image]

I tried using, firefox,chrome,safari but same problem occurs. I cleared already the cache and index. but nothing happen. I hope someone will help me. Thank you. I know only basic programming .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by modern browsers [blocking mixed active content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content), that is scripts and Ajax calls over HTTP on HTTPS sites.

Since this website uses HTTPS already, the solution would be to make sure **everything** is served over HTTPS:

1. Make sure that both [Secure and Unsecure base URLs](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/url-secure-unsecure.html) have the `https://` prefix (in the admin panel, under System > Configuration > Web).
2. Make sure that there are no hardcoded HTTP resources in themes or modules used in the project.

*Please be advised that misconfiguration of base URLs on the live website may lead to inability to log into the admin panel or even prevent the site from loading. Test the configuration on a staging environment first and make sure you have a backup of the live website in case anything goes wrong.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already tried to change the secure url from http to https, but after I save it, it will go back to http again.

Comment: Can you confirm that you've set **both** secure and unsecure URLs to use `https` in all relevant scopes and the issue persists even after you clear cache, log out and log back in?

Comment: I've set both secure and unsercure URLs to https, but after saving, the unsecure urls will go back to http. seems like the it didn't save but showing saved configuration. I already clear the cache,log out andlog back in. still the problem exist..

Comment: I only touch the admin panel of magento, I didn't touch the root directory.

Comment: When saving the configuration, do you get an error in the browser console? (Similar to what you posted in your original question)

Comment: When saving, there's a pop-up warning appear.  "The information you have entered on this page will be sent over an insecure connection and could be read by a third party. re you sure you want to send this information?"

Comment: or maybe the problem is with .htaccess it force rewrited all urls? I know how to access the .htaccess but I don't know what code should I add.

Comment: I Fix the issue. I edit directly to the database . I change the unsecure URLs from http to https directly from the MyPhpAdmin database. Then I flush the cache and it work perfectly fine now. all the errors are gone now. Thanks for the answer bro. I get the idea from your answer.